# How to create a Pandas pivot table with a column that is the count of an index?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, pivot-table

I have a dataframe that consists of 82 rows and 8 columns, that looks something like this

```
    Location  photo_pos Min_vis_point  ... valid_photo  photo_angle Distance
0          1          3           1.5  ...           j           20       10
1          1          3           1.5  ...           j           20       10
2          1          3           1.5  ...           j           20       10
3          1          9           1.5  ...           j           20       10
4          1          9           1.5  ...           j           20       10
..       ...        ...           ...  ...         ...          ...      ...
77         4          8           0.8  ...           j            0        7
78         4          5           0.8  ...           j            0        7
79         4          6             2  ...           j            0       10
80         4          9           1.5  ...           j            0       10
81         4          8           1.5  ...           j            0        7
```

From this dataframe, I want to create a pivot table that has as indexes the column location, Photo_pos, and Valid_photo, and that counts how many "j" or "n" are in each group.

Initially I achieved this with groupby() using the following code

```
'Grouping pictures by location in the blade and j/n criteria'
df_group_by_loc_valid=df.groupby(["Location","photo_pos","valid_photo"])["valid_photo"]

#Print the count of how many valid and not valid pictures for each location and position
print(df_group_by_loc_valid.count())
```

And it looks like this, which is exactly what I need:

```
Location  photo_pos  valid_photo
1         2          j              3
          3          j              3
          5          j              4
          6          j              5
          8          j              6
          9          j              5
2         3          j              4
                     n              2
          6          j              2
                     n              6
3         2          j              1
          3          j              3
          9          j              2
                     n              7
4         2          j              2
                     n              2
          5          j              1
          6          j              3
          8          j              2
          9          j              1
5         3          j              1
                     n              3
          6          j              4
          9          j              2
                     n              2
6         2          j              3
          3          j              1
          8          j              2
Name: valid_photo, dtype: int64
```

However, I also want to achieve this by means of a pivot table, but I haven´t been able to. The first closest result has been using this line:

```
pivot_table=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Location','photo_pos'], columns='valid_photo').fillna(0)
print(pivot_table)
```

Which prints something like:

```
                    valid_photo
Location photo_pos             
1        2                    3
         3                    3
         5                    4
         6                    5
         8                    6
         9                    5
2        3                    6
         6                    8
3        2                    1
         3                    3
         9                    9
4        2                    4
         5                    1
         6                    3
         8                    2
         9                    1
5        3                    4
         6                    4
         9                    4
6        2                    3
         3                    1
         8                    2
```

The problem is that the count of valid photos doesn´t differentiates between "j" or "n"

The second closest result has been using this line:

```
pivot_table=pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Location','photo_pos','valid_photo'], aggfunc='count')
print(pivot_table)
```

Which prints:

```
                                Distance  ...  photo_angle
Location photo_pos valid_photo            ...             
1        2         j                   3  ...            3
         3         j                   3  ...            3
         5         j                   4  ...            4
         6         j                   5  ...            5
         8         j                   6  ...            6
         9         j                   5  ...            5
2        3         j                   4  ...            4
                   n                   2  ...            2
         6         j                   2  ...            2
                   n                   6  ...            6
3        2         j                   1  ...            1
         3         j                   3  ...            3
         9         j                   2  ...            2
                   n                   7  ...            7
4        2         j                   2  ...            2
                   n                   2  ...            2
         5         j                   1  ...            1
         6         j                   3  ...            3
         8         j                   2  ...            2
         9         j                   1  ...            1
5        3         j                   1  ...            1
                   n                   3  ...            3
         6         j                   4  ...            4
         9         j                   2  ...            2
                   n                   2  ...            2
6        2         j                   3  ...            3
         3         j                   1  ...            1
         8         j                   2  ...            2
```

The problem in this case, is that is taking as columns the rest of the columns in the original data frame.

If I try to add a column called `valid_photo` I get the error `Grouper for 'valid_photo' not 1-dimensional`

As a reference, what I am trying to achieve looks in Excel like this:

[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZuSm.png)

[Pivot fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckJZk.png)

So I can plot something like this:

[Plot sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjPYM.png)

How can I achieve this?

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if we create a dummy variable of valid_photo & call it in pivot_table for grouping... Something like this below;

```
df["valid_photo_dummy"] = df["valid_photo"]

df1 = df.pivot_table(index = ['Location','photo_pos','valid_photo'],
                     values = 'valid_photo_dummy',
                     aggfunc='count')

df1.rename(columns={'valid_photo_dummy':'Frequency'}, inplace=True)
```

Not sure if this fulfill your requirement... Hope this Helps...